# How to disable Windows wireless power saving on the fly?

Tags: windows, wifi, ndis, power-saving

We have some issues with the wireless power saving. If we set the Power Saving Mode of Wireless Adapter Settings to Maximum Performance in the current power plan, all issues are gone. However, this does have an impact on the battery life. So we would like to find a way to turn off Wi-Fi power saving programmatically, only when our program is running.

We tried setting OID_DOT11_POWER_MGMT_REQUEST, but it failed with 0xC0010017, which means NDIS_STATUS_INVALID_OID. Querying is OK, though.

Another approach is to modify the current power scheme, but it may cause problems and confusions if the user switches the power scheme when our program is running.

Does a guru here know a better way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

OID_DOT11_POWER_MGMT_REQUEST shouldn't fail upon set. You should file a bug for your WiFi vendor.
Note, that the implementation of this oid is vendor responsibility thus the real power save you get is totally dependent on vendors' driver implementation and device characteristics.